# Comparing 2 datasets in R

Tags: r, dataset, compare, extract

I have 2 extracted data sets from a dataset called babies2009( 3 vectors count, name, gender )

One is girls2009 containing all the girls and the other boys2009.
I want to find out what similar names exist between boys and girls.

I tried this

```
common.names = (boys2009$name %in% girls2009$name)
```

When I try

```
babies2009[common.names, ] [1:10, ]
```

all I get is the girl names not the common names.

I have confirmed that both data sets indeed contain boys and girls respectively by doing taking a 10 sample...

```
boys2009 [1:10,]
girsl2009 [1:10,]
```

How else can I compare the 2 datasets and determine what values they both share.
Thanks,

Comment: You will get much better answers if you make your answers reproducible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`common.names = (boys2009$name %in% girls2009$name)` gives you a logical vector of length `length(boys2009$name)`.  So when you try selecting from a much longer data.frame `babies2009[common.names, ] [1:10, ]`, you wind up with nonsense.

Solution: use that logical vector on the proper data.frame!

```
boys2009 <- data.frame( names=c("Billy","Bob"),data=runif(2), gender="M" , stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
girls2009 <- data.frame( names=c("Billy","Mae","Sue"),data=runif(3), gender="F" , stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
babies2009 <- rbind(boys2009,girls2009)

common.names <- (boys2009$name %in% girls2009$name)

> boys2009[common.names, ]$names
[1] "Billy"
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you want similarities but did not specify exact matches, you should consider `agrep`

```
sapply(boys2009$name , agrep,  girls2009$name, max = 0.1)
```

You can adjust the max.distance argument to suit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

How about using [set functions](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/sets):

```
list(
    `only boys` = setdiff(boys2009$name, girls2009$name),
    `common` = intersect(boys2009$name, girls2009$name),
    `only girls` = setdiff(girls2009$name, boys2009$name)
)
```